# carrierwave fog storage

Tags: url, path, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I just cant figure out how to do this. I need to get the S3 path without the filename
`https://testphotobucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/51237a37ff770df332000007/`

and not like this
`https://testphotobucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/51237a37ff770df332000007/tiger.jpg`

but i keep getting this error.
undefined method `gallery_photo_path' for #<Gallery:0x007f94f4658778>
undefined method`gallery_photo_http_url' for #

just how do i get the path if im using fog as the storage ?

Thanks. below is my code snippet.

```
# models/gallery.rb
class Gallery

  include Mongoid::Document        

  mount_uploader :gallery_photo, PhotoUploader

# uploaders/photo_uploader.rb
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :fog

# views/galleries/show.html.erb
<%= image_tag @gallery.gallery_photo_url.to_s %>
path **<%= @gallery.gallery_photo_path.to_s %>**   <--- not working
httppath **<%= @gallery.gallery_photo_http_url.to_s %>** <--- not working

# the error:
undefined method `gallery_photo_path' for #<Gallery:0x007f94f4658778>
undefined method `gallery_photo_http_url' for #<Gallery:0x007f94f46431e8>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for isn't built into carrierwave. You should probably put this in a helper:

```
def uri_dirname(uri_string)
  uri = URI.parse(uri_string)
  uri.path = File.dirname(uri.path)
  uri.to_s
end
```

And then in your view you can use:

```
uri_dirname(@gallery.gallery_photo.uri)
```